# Visual Studio <AtlImplementationDetails> IntelliSense Error

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

i tried to import a VS sln file, probably created using VS 2010 or 2008, into
VS 2013 Ultimate. That went pretty well and i could rebuild the project.

Then i added the opencv libraries and it wouldn't compile, getting the following Errors in the atlbase.h file:

```
namespace __identifier("<AtlImplementationDetails>")
```

causes "IntelliSense: Expecting C++ Keyword" multiple times and

```
inline LSTATUS CRegKey::EnumKey(
_In_ DWORD iIndex,
_Out_writes_to_(*pnNameLength, *pnNameLength) _Post_z_ LPTSTR pszName,
_Inout_ LPDWORD pnNameLength,
_Out_opt_ FILETIME**  pftLastWriteTime) throw()
{
  FILETIME* ftLastWriteTime;

  ATLASSUME(m_hKey != NULL);
  if (pftLastWriteTime == NULL)
  {
      pftLastWriteTime = &ftLastWriteTime;
  }

return ::RegEnumKeyEx(m_hKey, iIndex, pszName, pnNameLength, NULL, NULL,    NULL, pftLastWriteTime);
}
```

causes "IntelliSense: FILETIME is ambigous" multiple times. To fix that, i changed it to

```
System::Runtime::InteropServices::ComTypes::FILETIME* ftLastWriteTime;
```

but that caused the following error:

```
7   IntelliSense: The Deklaration is not compatible with ""LSTATUS ATL::CRegKey::EnumKey(DWORD iIndex, LPTSTR pszName, LPDWORD pnNameLength, System::Runtime::InteropServices::ComTypes::FILETIME *pftLastWriteTime = (System::Runtime::InteropServices::ComTypes::FILETIME *)0)" (deklared in 5685 von "C:\VisualStudio\VC\atlmfc\include\AtlBase.h")".    c:\VisualStudio\VC\atlmfc\include\atlbase.h 5826    25  Start IPC2
```

Any ideas?

best,
hh

Comment: Have you specifically compiled the libs for VS2013?

Comment: Which libs do you mean?

Comment: Thanks so much! i didnt see the obvy. They were set to v11 instead of v12. now it works!

Comment: Hi Heinke, did changing your OpenCV libs from v11 to v12 fix your `IntelliSense: Expecting C++ Keyword` errors, or just the other error? I'm getting those errors, also in atlbase.h, but I'm not using OpenCV, and there's precious little help on the web for this error. I don't see how your OpenCV version would affect the Expecting C++ Keyword error in atlbase.h.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you have set your OpenCV Libraries to be the correct version of Visual Studio.

In this case change them from VS11 to VS12 and it will work. The errors you are getting will only take you down a path of misery and confusion.

Comment: in response to "Why did I repeat what was said in the comments?" - It's good for questions to have answers, that way they A. can get accepted and close the question and B. if somebody else comes looking for a solution when they have the same problem then they do not have to go trawling through the comments sections.